# Reading a file in Spark with newline(\n) in fields, escaped with backslash(\) and not quoted

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, spark-csv

I have an input file that has following structure,

```
    col1, col2, col3
    
    line1filed1,line1filed2.1\
    
    line1filed2.2, line1filed3
    
    line2filed1,line2filed2.1\
    
    line2filed2.2, line2filed3
    
    line3filed1, line3filed2, line3filed3
    
    line4filed1,line4filed2,
    
    line5filed1,,line5filed3
```

The output dataframe has to be,

```
    col1, col2, col3
    
    [line1filed1,line1filed2.1 line1filed2.2, line1filed3]
    
    [line2filed1,line2filed2.1 line2filed2.2, line2filed3]
    
    [line3filed1, line3filed2, line3filed3]
    
    [line4filed1,line4filed2, null]
    
    [line5filed1, null, line5filed3]
```

I'm trying to do

```scala
    spark
    .read
    .option("multiLine", "true")
    .option("escape", "\\")
    .csv("path to file")
```

Some solutions suggest going `wholeTextFiles`, but it is also mentioned that `wholeTextFiles` is not an optimal solution.

What would be the right way to do this?

**P.S:** I do have an input production file of `50GB`.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this piece of code.

I think it can be improved but maybe it can give you some clues to resolve your problem.

```scala
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

/**
  * col1, col2, col3
  * [line1filed1,line1filed2.1 line1filed2.2, line1filed3]
  * [line2filed1,line2filed2.1 line2filed2.2, line2filed3]
  * [line3filed1, line3filed2, line3filed3]
  * [line4filed1,line4filed2, null]
  * [line5filed1, null, line5filed3]
  */

object Multiline2 {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Multiline2")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "4") //Change to a more reasonable default number of partitions for our data
    .config("spark.app.id", "Multiline2")  // To silence Metrics warning
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  val input = "/home/cloudera/files/tests/multiline2.csv"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    try {
      Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

      val data = sc.textFile(input)
      val header = data.first()
      val columns = header.split(",")

      import spark.implicits._

      var aux = ""
      val multiline = data
          .filter(line => !line.equals(header))
          .map(line => {
            if(line.contains("\")) {
              aux = line.substring(0,line.lastIndexOf("\"))
              ""
            } else {
              val l = s"$aux $line"
              aux = ""
              l
            }
          })
          .filter(line => !line.equals(""))
          .map(line => line.split(","))
          .map(r =>{ r.length match {
            case 2 => (r(0).trim,r(1).trim,"")
            case _ => (r(0).trim,r(1).trim,r(2).trim)
          }})
          .toDF(columns(0).trim, columns(1).trim, columns(2).trim)

      multiline.show()

      // To have the opportunity to view the web console of Spark: http://localhost:4040/
      println("Type whatever to the console to exit......")
      scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
    } finally {
      sc.stop()
      println("SparkContext stopped.")
      spark.stop()
      println("SparkSession stopped.")
    }
  }
}
```

```sql
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
|       col1|                col2|       col3|
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
|line1filed1|line1filed2.1 lin...|line1filed3|
|line2filed1|line2filed2.1 lin...|line2filed3|
|line3filed1|         line3filed2|line3filed3|
|line4filed1|         line4filed2|           |
|line5filed1|                    |line5filed3|
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
```